# S3 state file does not get created when using Terraform workspaces

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am using S3 backend for my Terraform scripts:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

If I use multiple workspaces, will the state of all my workspaces be stored in the above mentioned S3 backend state file?

I tried creating 2 workspaces and the state file does not even get created on the S3 bucket mentioned above.

What am I missing?

Comment: In your bucket you should see a folder `env:` unless you've configured it to be a different one, see the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#workspace_key_prefix). In this folder you would find folders for each workspace, e.g. for a workspace called `dev` your state file would be located at `env:/dev/path/to/my/key`. Is there any error message? Do you have resources being created?

Comment: That'd mean I should have a separate main.tf file (which declares the backend as shown in the code snippet in my question) for each environment?

Comment: No. Terraform does the management of your state files if you work with workspaces, you just need to ensure the bucket exists. Then you do a `terraform workspace select <my workspace>` and `terraform apply`. Is there any error being displayed?

Comment: I don't get error. Resources are getting created perfectly fine. But my bucket (for storing state file) itself is not getting created. It appears state is stored in local folder and not on S3.

Comment: Terraform *won't* create the S3 bucket which stores your state, you have to *manually* create it yourself. Have a look in the [Terraform Backend S3 documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#administrative-account-setup).

Answer (score 2):

Terraform will create the state file in the bucket depending on which workspace you've selected with a [workspace key prefix](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html#workspace_key_prefix), the default settings will give you something like this:

```
 env:/<my workspace>/path/to/my/key
```

That means if you run `terraform workspace select <my workspace>` and `terraform apply` the state file for the selected workspace will end up in the above folder.

However for storing state on an S3 bucket you will need to create the S3 storage bucket yourself (Terraform expects it to exist).

You can use the following commands:

```
aws s3 mb s3://<my bucket> --region <my region>
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning \
    --region <my region> \
    --bucket <my bucket> \
    --versioning-configuration "Status=Enabled"
aws s3api put-public-access-block \
    --region <my region> \
    --bucket <my bucket> \
    --public-access-block-configuration "BlockPublicAcls=true,IgnorePublicAcls=true,BlockPublicPolicy=true,RestrictPublicBuckets=true"
```

Terraform also recommends using a DynamoDB table for locking, you can create it like this:

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
    --region <my region> \
    --table-name <my dynamodb lock table> \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=LockID,AttributeType=S \
    --key-schema AttributeName=LockID,KeyType=HASH
```

You will need to add the name of the DynamoDB lock table in your backend configuration then with `dynamodb_table = "<my dynamodb lock table>"`.

Comment: was s3 mb s3://<my bucket>. What should <my bucket> be? And inside that bucket, will terraform create "env:" folder and then create "<workspace name>" folder inside "env:" and then create a state file there with the name of the key provided in `backend "s3"` block?

Comment: `<my bucket>` is the name you want to give your S3 bucket, e.g. `my-test-state-bucket`. Replace all the `<>` placeholders with your desired values. The S3 bucket should be empty, Terraform will create all the necessary folders in there. And yes your thinking of the path name is correct.